# Why is my command not working (rock paper scissors)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am doing a rock paper scissors command and I'm trying to keep it basic. No reactions, it checks your arguments and then the bot tells you what it chose. Code:

```
@client.command(aliases=["rockpaperscissors"])
async def rps(ctx, args):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if args == ("rock" or "paper" or "scissors" or "Rock" or "Paper" or "Scissors"):
        embed=discord.Embed(title='Rock paper scissors', description='You selected ' + args + f' - Bot selected {random.choice(rps)}.', color=RandomColor())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    else:
        await ctx.send("Your option needs to be either rock, paper or scissors.")
```

So I was wondering what's wrong with my command. Is it the color?

Comment: I have now fixed this error myself. It is fine

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line:

```py
if args == ("rock" or "paper" or "scissors" or "Rock" or "Paper" or "Scissors"):
```

The right operand is a boolean, so it'll never be equal to a string. It should be instead

```py
if args in ("rock", "paper", "scissors", "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"):
```

or even

```py
if args.lower() in ("rock", "paper", "scissors"):
```

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work, the line after the args check line is where I'm getting the error.

Comment: @ineedhelp And *what's* the error?

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'Command' has no len()

Comment: Do you see any `len()` in the answer provided? The error you're describing is not even remotely related to your original question.

Comment: The reason I posted this question was because of an error. People don't post questions with no problems. Unless they are curious, and I am not curious.

Comment: You're not using `len` anywhere in the code snippet in your question, telling us a random error you're getting is simply useless @ineedhelp